# ManyToMany Form saving in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to save a ManyToMany field to my database if the user submits the form. When the user submits the form, I can see the non-M2M fields in the database, but even when selecting the M2M fields they will not show up. I have been searching around a lot and seen some things about the m2m_save() function but couldn't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated! (I have been searching for a long time, so I hope I am not repeating this question!)

```
# models.py

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contactinfo = models.ForeignKey(ContactInfo)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True)
    work = models.ManyToManyField(Work, null=True, blank=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills, null=True, blank=True)
    contactgroup = models.ManyToManyField(ContactGroup, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["first_name",]



#forms.py

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        #exclude = ('work', 'skills', 'contactgroup')
        first_name = forms.TextInput(),
        last_name = forms.TextInput(),
        contactinfo = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ContactInfo.objects.all()),
        location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all()),
        work = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Work.objects.all()),
        skills = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Skills.objects.all()),
        contactgroup = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ContactGroup.objects.all()),
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last'}),
        }


# views.py 
def apphome(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    form1 = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form1.is_valid():
        new_contact = form1.save(commit=False)
        new_contact.save()
        new_contact.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/app")

    return render_to_response("apphome.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I run this, I receive this:

```
AttributeError at /app/
'Contact' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save_m2m` is a method on the form, not on `new_contact` (which is an instance of the model).

But you don't need to call it at all if you miss out the `commit=False` to the form save. The only reason for having `save_m2m` is for when you do use `commit=False`, which you would want to do if you want to set any instance fields before saving properly. If you don't want to do that, as here, just do `form1.save()` directly, then there's no need to call either `new_contact.save()` or `save_m2m()`.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked great! You are a wonderful person!